# How to view direct excel report from iReport 2.0.2

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have problems to view excel report from *iReports 2.0.2* because it does not want to go out when I click the preview button to excel. It just appears in the folder only. When I open the excel file in the report, I see the data does not follow the order of table row and column.

What I want is when I click the preview button excel, then the report will continue to view direct from the report and the alignment follow the row and column.

Comment: Please read your question and try to make it clear. Also, are you running the same report on both versions of iReport or modified versions?

Comment: now im running the reports using ireports 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

iReport 2, unlike the 3.5 or greater versions, doesn't have the ability to show preview within it the application. This especially applies to excel reports. You can set a specific external application for each export type in the options dialog. As for the formatting problem, you have not posted any code so I doubt anyone could help. You probably made an error during downgrade of the report.